# How to sort based on two column but keep specific strings together

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data like below.
I am trying to sort them

```
    df<-structure(list(string = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CGSKDNIKHVPGGGSVQIVYKPVDLSK", 
"ESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK", "KDQGGYTMHQDQEGDTDAGLKESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK", 
"SKDGTGSDDKK", "SPSSAKSRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVK", "SRLQTAPVPMPDLK", "SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK", 
"SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK", "VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK"), class = "factor"), 
    key = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Mys: G52: ru1", 
    "Mys: G52: ru2", "Mys: G52: ru3"), class = "factor"), val = structure(c(3L, 
    13L, 16L, 15L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 
    4L, 10L, 14L), .Label = c("1442983324", "1451319531", "1512864.443", 
    "1612410048", "16349475.63", "1784901841", "30553282.01", 
    "317403612.9", "3612004.547", "3686081.063", "39135868.44", 
    "43701608", "64223793.8", "64959501.42", "775987137.8", "9767666215"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("string", "key", "val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

I try to sort them based on two column.first column based on the size (number of letters) and second one keep them together (ru1, ru2, ru3 etc.) (ru1, ru2, ru3) etc. etc.

The needed output should look like below

The following command does not work

```
df2 <- df[order(df$string, df$key), ]
```

Which should be sorted like this

```
SKDGTGSDDKK               Mys: G52: ru1            1512864.443
SKDGTGSDDKK               Mys: G52: ru2            64223793.8
SKDGTGSDDKK               Mys: G52: ru3            9767666215
VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK          Mys: G52: ru1            775987137.8
VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK          Mys: G52: ru2            1784901841
SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK       Mys: G52: ru2            1442983324
SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK       Mys: G52: ru3            30553282.01
SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK       Mys: G52: ru1            317403612.9
SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK Mys: G52: ru3          43701608
SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK Mys: G52: ru2          1612410048
```

Comment: `df[order(nchar(as.character(df$string)), df$key), ]` this puts you one step ahead. But question is, what if you had both `ru1` and `ru3` in two consecutive groups (`string`). How do you handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Hadley's tidyverse functions:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_sorted <- df %>% 
    # get length of string
    mutate(length_string = map_dbl(as.character(string), nchar)) %>%
    # arrange first by number of characters, then string, then key
    arrange(length_string, string, key) %>%
    # remove length column
    select(-length_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

split second column by semicolumn

```
listdf<-strsplit(as.character(df[,2]),split=":")
```

extract vector from list

```
listdf3<-sapply(listdf, function(X)X[3])
```

calculate order
    df[order(nchar(as.character(df[,1])),listdf3),]

```
                                     string           key         val
1                                   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru1 1512864.443
2                                   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru2  64223793.8
3                                   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru3  9767666215
6                                SRLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531
7                                SRLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531
4                              VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK Mys: G52: ru1 775987137.8
5                              VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK Mys: G52: ru2  1784901841
13                          SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK Mys: G52: ru1 317403612.9
11                          SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK Mys: G52: ru2  1442983324
12                          SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK Mys: G52: ru3 30553282.01
8                       SPSSAKSRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVK Mys: G52: ru1 39135868.44
9                       ESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK Mys: G52: ru1 3612004.547
10                  CGSKDNIKHVPGGGSVQIVYKPVDLSK Mys: G52: ru1 16349475.63
15                  SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK Mys: G52: ru2  1612410048
14                  SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK Mys: G52: ru3    43701608
16 KDQGGYTMHQDQEGDTDAGLKESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK Mys: G52: ru3 3686081.063
17 KDQGGYTMHQDQEGDTDAGLKESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK Mys: G52: ru3 64959501.42
```

Comment: In a real data I get something like this for example for one of the listdf ` " sam1\", \"Area"   " G10" ` or for another one ` " sam3\", \n\"Area" " G73" `. do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: Not sure, it is normal that you get three separate values at each position of the list. Is it what you see, the next line sapply(... extracts the last element.

Comment: unfortunately I don't see like the ru1 , ru2 etc etc. I liked your answer anyway. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to first calculate the length of the `string` and then order based on that column. I did this by first creating a new data frame (`df_tmp`) and then merging it into `df2`.

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
df_tmp <- data.frame(names=df$string,chr=apply(df,2,nchar)[,1])
colnames(df_tmp)[1] <- "string"
df2 <- inner_join(df, df_tmp)
df2 <- df2[order(df2$chr, df2$key), ]
```

**Extracxt of the result**

```
     string           key         val chr
     SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru1 1512864.443  11
     SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru1 1512864.443  11
     SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru1 1512864.443  11
     SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru2  64223793.8  11
    SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru2  64223793.8  11
   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru2  64223793.8  11
    SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru3  9767666215  11
     SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru3  9767666215  11
    SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru3  9767666215  11
     SRLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531  14
     SRLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531  14
   RLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531  14
    SRLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531  14
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `nchar()` function, but first you must convert `df$string` from `factor` to `character` type.

Here's a solution using `tidyverse` tools:

```r
library('tidyverse')

df<-structure(list(string = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 
                                        5L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CGSKDNIKHVPGGGSVQIVYKPVDLSK", 
                                                                                            "ESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK", "KDQGGYTMHQDQEGDTDAGLKESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK", 
                                                                                            "SKDGTGSDDKK", "SPSSAKSRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVK", "SRLQTAPVPMPDLK", "SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK", 
                                                                                            "SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK", "VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK"), class = "factor"), 
                   key = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Mys: G52: ru1", 
                                                                             "Mys: G52: ru2", "Mys: G52: ru3"), class = "factor"), val = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                                                                                                     13L, 16L, 15L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                                     4L, 10L, 14L), .Label = c("1442983324", "1451319531", "1512864.443", 
                                                                                                                                                                               "1612410048", "16349475.63", "1784901841", "30553282.01", 
                                                                                                                                                                               "317403612.9", "3612004.547", "3686081.063", "39135868.44", 
                                                                                                                                                                               "43701608", "64223793.8", "64959501.42", "775987137.8", "9767666215"
                                                                                                                                                     ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("string", "key", "val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -17L))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(string = as.character(string)) %>%
  arrange(nchar(string), key)

df2

#>                                          string           key         val
#> 1                                   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru1 1512864.443
#> 2                                   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru2  64223793.8
#> 3                                   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru3  9767666215
#> 4                                SRLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531
#> 5                                SRLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531
#> 6                              VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK Mys: G52: ru1 775987137.8
#> 7                              VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK Mys: G52: ru2  1784901841
#> 8                           SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK Mys: G52: ru1 317403612.9
#> 9                           SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK Mys: G52: ru2  1442983324
#> 10                          SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK Mys: G52: ru3 30553282.01
#> 11                      SPSSAKSRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVK Mys: G52: ru1 39135868.44
#> 12                      ESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK Mys: G52: ru1 3612004.547
#> 13                  CGSKDNIKHVPGGGSVQIVYKPVDLSK Mys: G52: ru1 16349475.63
#> 14                  SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK Mys: G52: ru2  1612410048
#> 15                  SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK Mys: G52: ru3    43701608
#> 16 KDQGGYTMHQDQEGDTDAGLKESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK Mys: G52: ru3 3686081.063
#> 17 KDQGGYTMHQDQEGDTDAGLKESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK Mys: G52: ru3 64959501.42
```

Here's a solution using base R tools, as you're using in your example:

```r
df<-structure(list(string = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 
                                        5L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CGSKDNIKHVPGGGSVQIVYKPVDLSK", 
                                                                                            "ESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK", "KDQGGYTMHQDQEGDTDAGLKESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK", 
                                                                                            "SKDGTGSDDKK", "SPSSAKSRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVK", "SRLQTAPVPMPDLK", "SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK", 
                                                                                            "SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK", "VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK"), class = "factor"), 
                   key = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Mys: G52: ru1", 
                                                                             "Mys: G52: ru2", "Mys: G52: ru3"), class = "factor"), val = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                                                                                                     13L, 16L, 15L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                                     4L, 10L, 14L), .Label = c("1442983324", "1451319531", "1512864.443", 
                                                                                                                                                                               "1612410048", "16349475.63", "1784901841", "30553282.01", 
                                                                                                                                                                               "317403612.9", "3612004.547", "3686081.063", "39135868.44", 
                                                                                                                                                                               "43701608", "64223793.8", "64959501.42", "775987137.8", "9767666215"
                                                                                                                                                     ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("string", "key", "val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -17L))

df2 <- df[order(nchar(as.character(df$string)), df$key),]

df2

#>                                          string           key         val
#> 1                                   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru1 1512864.443
#> 2                                   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru2  64223793.8
#> 3                                   SKDGTGSDDKK Mys: G52: ru3  9767666215
#> 6                                SRLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531
#> 7                                SRLQTAPVPMPDLK Mys: G52: ru1  1451319531
#> 4                              VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK Mys: G52: ru1 775987137.8
#> 5                              VQIINKKLDLSNVQSK Mys: G52: ru2  1784901841
#> 13                          SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK Mys: G52: ru1 317403612.9
#> 11                          SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK Mys: G52: ru2  1442983324
#> 12                          SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSK Mys: G52: ru3 30553282.01
#> 8                       SPSSAKSRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVK Mys: G52: ru1 39135868.44
#> 9                       ESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK Mys: G52: ru1 3612004.547
#> 10                  CGSKDNIKHVPGGGSVQIVYKPVDLSK Mys: G52: ru1 16349475.63
#> 15                  SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK Mys: G52: ru2  1612410048
#> 14                  SRLQTAPVPMPDLKNVKSKIGSTENLK Mys: G52: ru3    43701608
#> 16 KDQGGYTMHQDQEGDTDAGLKESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK Mys: G52: ru3 3686081.063
#> 17 KDQGGYTMHQDQEGDTDAGLKESPLQTPTEDGSEEPGSETSDAK Mys: G52: ru3 64959501.42
```